# Python is telling me 66 <= 17

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and trying to build a program that evaluates whether a potential partner is too young for someone using the / 2 + 7 rule.

despite using test variables that are well above 18 the program executes line 7 no matter what I do. I used 88/77, 77/66, 19/19, it always executes line 7.

```
num1 = float(input("What is the higher age number? "))
num2 = float(input("What is the lower age number? "))
output = num1 / 2 + 7
if num1 and num2 <= 17:
    print("You're both underage")
elif num2 <= 17:
    print("You're going to jail bud")
elif output <= num2:
    print("That's OK")
else:
    print("They are slightly too young for you")
```

EDIT:

I made the fix that many suggested, but now the program is still not working as intended and I found another flaw.

```
num1 = float(input("What is the higher age number? "))
num2 = float(input("What is the lower age number? "))
output = num1 / 2 + 7
if num1 <= 17 and num2 <= 17:
    print("You're both underage")
elif num2 <= 17:
    print("You're going to jail bud")
elif output <= num2:
    print("That's OK")
else:
    print("They are slightly too young for you")
```

when num1 = 19 and num2 = 16, the program outputs line 5 when I want it to output line 7. It's also still outputting line 7 when num1 and num2 are both set to a value higher than 17.

Comment: I dunno about line 7, but `if num1 and num2 <= 17` will always be `True` unless `num1` is 0. Do `if num1 <= 17 and num2 <= 17` instead.

Comment: Are you still having this problem @Brandon? Because the code works for all the test cases you printed, I just tested it.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I was running the wrong .py file in the terminal -_-

Comment: Haha, that's happened to me countless times...

Comment: @Brandon, If a solution below solved your problem, please accept it (tick on left). You may also upvote any other solutions that you found helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression :

```
if num1 and num2 <= 17:
```

is like :

```
if num1 == True and num2 <= 17:
```

With `num1=66`, `num1` is similar to `True` and `num2 <= 17` is evaluated

To fix your program, You need write :

```
if num1 <= 17 and num2 <= 17:
```

> From python documention : [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Answer (score 4):

The issue is for this line of code:

```
if num1 and num2 <= 17:
```

Python reads this as follows:

> if num1 is TRUE (which it is) and num2 is less or equal to 17, then
>   execute ...

You were looking for

```
if num1 <= 17 and num2 <= 17
```

Or even:

```
if all(i <= 17 for i in [num1,num2])
```

in case you want to check more than two partners eventually (i.e. you hold a list of num1, num2, num3 ...)

Answer (score 4):

To write `num1 and num2 <= 17` in Python, you need to be explicit:

```
if num1 <= 17 and num2 <= 17:
    # do something
```

Otherwise, provided `num1 != 0`, the condition will always be `True`.

Or just use the `max` of the two values for the equivalent logic:

```
if max(num1, num2) <= 17:
    # do something
```